# Improve Ubuntu 14.04 LTS video performance

Tags: performance

System info:

$ lspci

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV44 [GeForce 6500] (rev a1)
```

$ free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7940       7646        294         49        168       3908
-/+ buffers/cache:       3568       4372
Swap:         8143          0       8143
```

cpu:

```
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 8192 KB
```

$ sudo lshw -short

```
H/W path        Device      Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         System Product Name (SKU)
/0                          bus            P8H77-M LE
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
/0/4/5                      memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                      memory         256KiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                      memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/1                        memory         
/0/1/0                      memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
/0/58                       memory         System Memory
/0/58/0                     memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
/0/2                        memory         
/0/3                        memory         
/0/100                      bridge         2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
/0/100/1/0                  display        NV44 [GeForce 6500]
/0/100/14                   bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                   communication  7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/1a                   bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
/0/100/1b                   multimedia     7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                   bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
/0/100/1c.5                 bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
/0/100/1c.5/0   eth0        network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.6                 bridge         82801 PCI Bridge
/0/100/1c.6/0               bridge         ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
/0/100/1d                   bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
/0/100/1f                   bridge         H77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 storage        7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1f.3                 bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/5            scsi0       storage        
/0/5/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           500GB WDC WD5000AAKX-0
/0/5/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1   volume         243MiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/5/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2   volume         465GiB Extended partition
/0/5/0.0.0/2/5  /dev/sda5   volume         465GiB Linux LVM Physical Volume partition
/0/6            scsi4       storage        
/0/6/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk           CDDVDW SH-222BB
/1                          power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

Installed nvidia-304 proprietary driver.

The system sometimes getting extremely slow especially performing desktop video effects (all those fade-ins and fade-outs, blurs, etc.)

Previously I had Ubuntu 10.04 and I didn't have any issues with performance.

Is this due to poor video card which is scored just 68 at `glmark2` test?
What can I do to improve overall performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently nvidia drivers are written clumsy, after removing nvidia graphics card and staying with built-in one graphics performance improved drastically.

Might help somebody having the same issue.

Comment: I also did that, still I want the damn nVidia to perform properly on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

With NVIDIA, your only choice is to either use the proprietary drivers or live with horrible performance. Try installing nvidia-current.

Comment: nvidia-304 proprietary driver was already installed, added to my question